# wxPython 3.0.2.0 installation not working

Tags: python, installation, wxpython

I am trying to install wxPython 3.0.2.0 from source. When I run *$ sudo* *python* *setup.py* *install*, I get the following error message (part of output shown). System is 32-bit Edubuntu 12.04.

```
copying wx/tools/Editra/TODO -> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/wx-3.0-gtk2/wx/tools/Editra
running install_egg_info
Writing /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/wx-3.0-gtk2/wxPython-3.0.2.0.egg-info
warning: wx_install: path file '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/wx-3.0-gtk2.pth' not created
```

I went on ahead to run python and then try to import the module. This is the error message I get.

```
>>> import wx
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "wx/__init__.py", line 46, in <module>
    del wx
NameError: name 'wx' is not defined
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you confirmed all the dependencies have been installed?

Comment: As far as I can tell yes

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to install wxPython 3.0.0 from source using checkinstall. First of all do:

> sudo apt-get install checkinstall

After that download the wxPython source code, extract to a directory and create a a directory in the source code folder. Assuming the source code is extracted to ~/wxPython-src-3.0.0/

> mkdir bld
>
> sudo checkinstall -y --pkgname=wxpython --pkgversion=3.0.0 --pkgrelease=1 --pkglicense=wxWidgets --pkgsource=http://www.wxpython.org/ --maintainer=reingart@gmail.com --requires=python-wxversion,python2.7,python -D  python build-wxpython.py --build_dir=../bld --install

This creates a debian package before installing wxPython.